# In $\mathbb Z_{10}$ show that $7\mid5$ and in $\mathbb Z_{12}$ show that $5\mid8$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Help I don't know where to start. I don't think I understand if I'm in mod 10 it will never be $7$ away from $10$ only ever $5$.

Comment: But $7 +7=2*7  \equiv 4 \pmod {10}$ so $7|4$.  That's $4$ away; not $7$.  And $7+ 7 + 7 = 3*7 \equiv 1 \pmod{10}$ and that's $1$ away; not $7$.

Answer (score 2):

If $7|5$, then there is some number $x$ such that $7x\equiv 5\pmod{10}$.  Absent any intuition or insight, one can just try plugging in $x=0,1,2,\ldots,9$. For each, simplify $7x$, modulo $10$, and see if you get $5$.

A similar strategy will solve the second problem.